# Webots: create node programatically

Tags: java, webots

I have a simulation where a robot simulate an ants behavior: while on his way back to the nest, the robot leaves a trail. In the real world ants use trail pheromones to achieve this.

To emulate these pheromones in the simulation I want my robot to leave Balls behind him while on his way to the nest. 
So my problem is: I want to create Ball Nodes programatically from the robot´s controller code.

Is it possible to do this? I'm using Java.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible, the Supervisor API is made for this: https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/supervisor

Here is a simulation where a robot leave a trail after him using the Supervisor API: https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/samples-howto#supervisor_draw_trail-wbt